# Is this the correct way to use Try-Catch with async-wait in dependent function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, try-catch

These are my following code files.

**flamesHelper.js**

```
import flames from "../model/flames";

async function count(query = {}) {
  try {
    return await flames.count(query).exec();
  } catch (error) {
    return new Error(error);
  }
}
```

**flamesController.js**

```
import flamesHelper from "../helpers/flamesHelper";
const flamePerPage = 100;

async function count(req, res) {
  try {
    const count = await flamesHelper.count();
    return res.status(200).send({ count, flamePerPage });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).send({ message: "Error while counting flames." });
  }
}
```

**flames.js**

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
import flamesController from "../controllers/flamesController";

router.get("/getCount", loginUtil.isLoggedIn, flamesController.count);
```

This is a simple NodeJS code. I need help in to understand if my code is correct. 
The code works fine I get correct count. I might use same structure for the whole project.

But my question is.

If at anytime from `flamesHelper.count` if any error occurred will be catch by `flamesController.count` method.
Also if you can tell me is this is correct way to use `async-await` with `try-catch` which involves **Mongodb** using `mongoose`.

Thank you in adv!

Comment: What is your intention with `return new Error(error)` in flamesHelper.js?

Comment: @Herohtar to return any error that might have occurred while counting. This that the correct way ? I'm not sure.

Comment: You don't need the try/catch in flamesHelper.js if you are just wanting the error to bubble up to the calling function -- it will already do that by default.

Comment: so you mean just `return await flames.count(query).exec();` will return the error if occurred and also will be handled by the `flamesController.count` method. `async function count(query = {}) {
  return await flames.count(query).exec();
}`

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Herohtar thanks for the help can you provide me some docs or examples where i can understand this scenario better ?

Comment: `catch (error) {
    return new Error(error);
  }` is never a good idea. This will never lead to the `500` status error, since  `count()` will never throw an exception. It will `return` the exception!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you're intending to do (per your comments), you can just do this:

```
function count(query = {}) {
    return flames.count(query).exec();
}
```

This will just return the promise and that returned promise will then either resolve or reject.  There's no need to use `await` with the simple code you show.

And, with what you had in your question, if you wanted the error to still be a rejected promise, you would have to either `throw err` or return `Promise.reject(err)`.  `return new Error(...)` would make for a resolved promise with the error object as the resolved value which is pretty much never what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed. explanation. So, i can just return the db query it will be handled pretty much handler in my `controller.js`. Can i follow the same structure with any kind of mongoDB query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch block in `flamesHelper.js` if you are going to customize DB exceptions and return mapped error to the controller.

flamesHelper.js

```
import flames from "../model/flames";

     async function count(query = {}) {
       try {
           return await flames.count(query).exec();
          } catch (error) {
            throw Error('Unable to count flames');

         // Or check db errors and map each error to user friendly error
         }
        }
```

flamesController.js

```
        import flamesHelper from "../helpers/flamesHelper";
        const flameDetailsPerPage = 100;

       async function count(req, res) {
           try {
                    const count = await flamesHelper.count();
                    return res.status(200).send({ count, flamePerPage });
           } catch (error) {
                 console.log(error);
                // Return mapped error.
                return res.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
            }
         }
```

In your case you are thrown the same error so no need to try catch block in helper.js just returned the query results and if there's any errors you will catch it in the controller.

```
  async function count(query = {}) {

       return flames.count(query).exec();

     }
```

And leave controller as is.

Comment: can you give me some examples pls

Comment: If you want to map errors in `flamesHelper.js` you can use try catch block the same you mentioned but instead of `return new Error(error)` you can customize that error message to be your custom message by `throw Error('Unable to count flames !');`  or you can check db errors and map each predictable to your custom message then in controller in catch block you can add `error.message` in response body directly , or instead you can return the db query like @jfriend00 answer , and leave controller as is.